# Disable namespace usage is certain classes/files

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm working on a plugin system for my CMS, inside my CMS I use namespaces a lot.
What I would like to have is that the developers of the plugins don't have to use namespaces inside their plugin, because they can be very complicated for developers who doesn't have used namespaces before. The main problem with the namespaces is the events which can be registered. Right now, plugin developers have to load an Event class using `use \events\Event;`, and if they just import the class they are still not able to use `new Event();` because it uses namespaces. What I would like to have is that they can just use `new Event();` (The class itself would be autoloaded by the CMS's auto loader, so no include required).

So basically, I would like to have namespaces disabled in certain classes or files. So `new \events\Event();` will just look like `new Event();` without removing the `namespace events;` from the `Event` class.

I hope I explained it clear, I'm not the best in explaining this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In other words, this won't work:

```
namespace Foo {
    class Event {}
    include('plugin.php');   // plugin.php cannot just do new Event();
}
```

That shouldn't be a problem really, since your CMS's plugin development documentation should be clear about the namespace usage and plugin developers would simply need to write something like

```
use Plugin\Namespace\Events\MyEventType;
```

to refer to `MyEventType` without needing to qualify it. Surely that's not too much to ask of plugin authors?

Comment: I think you are right, and they are not hard to use, but for people who didn't used them before they can be complicated. I'll take a look at the global namespace thing of Jack first, if that isn't the thing I'm searching for I'm probably going with this option. Thanks for your reply anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand completely, but to run code in "global" namespace, you can do this:

```
namespace {
    // this runs in global namespace
}
```

See also: [Defining multiple namespaces in the same file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer in the first place. I think this is not really what I'm searching for, I mean the plugin developers need to use `namespace { }` in the first place, but also the namespace usage is not really disabled. For example if I want to load an event from a Plugin, you need to use `use \events\Event;`, and that's actually what I want to prevent, cause it's complicated for PHP beginners. It's probably that you understood my explanation wrong, my bad, cause I'm not good at explaining. I think I'm just going with the namespaces. I just have to document it good explained then.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it is not possible, but if you use a loader that includes the needed files so that a plugin author could include a class with `loader::load('someclass');` you  can let the loader return the full classname with namespace and the plugin could use it:

```
$em_classname = Loader::load('eventmanager');
//dymamic use
$em = new $em_classname;
$em->registerEvent();
//static use
$em_classname::registerEvent();
```

For dynamic use you could even return an instance of the class instead of the class name.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you're trying to tell me. But the main goal of fully removing the need of namespaces in certain classes or files doesn't seem to be possible. Thanks for your reply btw.
Oh and, if you had problems understanding my problem, I edited my question and it's better explained right now.

Comment: Not sure but for a php beginner it might be the easiest way to use `$eventxyz = load('eventxyz');` where load() is some cms function that includes the needed file(s) and returns an instance of the requested class.